# What's the best way to arrange a large number of filters?

Tags: forms, search

I'm building a page that allows users to select "Accounts" in an enterprise software system (Salesforce.com).  At first there were only three filters and positioning them all horizontally worked pretty well.  As more filters have gotten added the display seems to be getting cluttered.

Does this clutter matter?  I'm assuming that if a user is motivated the find a record they'll find the filters without much issue, but I'd love to know if there are any design patterns out there that could improve on my current design.

[image: AccountViewerImage]

Comment: Is this the only search form or is there a "simple" search form and this is the "advanced" version?

Comment: at the moment it's always advanced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As users read in F pattern http://www.useit.com/alertbox/reading_pattern.html
I would suggest you place all the filters in a column on the left side. And make the filters fixed so they would always appear on the left.
[image: Salesforce mock-up]

sorry for terrible mock-up :)

Comment: upvoted! I am assuming these are table specific filters, column specific filters should still be triggered with a dropdown menu on each column

Answer (score 1):

I think there's not much to be done here, the filters area is very explicit as it is, easy to find and understand, if you know which filters are used the most then you can present a simple form with an advanced filtering option to clear some space, or maybe start grouping them in accordion style, which also clears space and provides order.

Comment: Great point about consolidating into the advanced section the least used filters. For the accordion styles any chance you have a example image somewhere?  I've searched around and the only options are more menu-centric and I'm having trouble figuring out how the filter accordion view would look

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was thinking something like this accordion menu http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-accordion-menu-jquery/  but grouping filters inside of it instead of links, this could help provide order and some context to the filtering area as well as clearing some space cause the filters are not always shown until the accordion is opened. regards

Comment: I'm glad it was usefull good luck Ralph!

Answer (score 1):

I agree the filters are easy to use and understand, the only suggestion I'd make is organise them either alphabetically or match the ordering of the table headers below.